# Optimal control for buy / sell / hold with fixed cost

Tags: optimization, optimal-control, dynamic-programming, linear-control

Consider the economic optimisation problem connected with stock. We can buy (open long position), sell (open short position), close or do nothing.
What is optimal (maximizing profit) control algorithm for trading (buy, sell or hold/wait) if we have known series of prices ($p_1, p_2, ..., p_T$)? Each opening of position requires fixed cost $J$. Each position has the same size. We can have only one position open at the moment. We can close and open position at the same time.
I don't know is it good idea to model it using dynamic programming. Without costs problem is easy. Buying / selling in local supremum is solution. But using cost problem becomes more complicated.

Comment: I am not finding the problem statement clear.  What is a "series of prices"?  Price as a function of time?  What is "opening of position"?  For that matter, what is a "position"?  Short vs. long?

Comment: I made edit. Yes, I mean price as function of time (e.g daily prices). Yes, position is long (buy) or short (sell).

Answer (score 0):

Better.  Two points: (1) dynamic programming is not a model, it is a solution method for problems in optimal control.  (2)  Your problem is a problem in discrete optimization, not in optimal control.  Namely, something like this:

Let $A$ be the constant size (amount) of a position; i.e., the amount of shares to be bought or sold (if I understand correctly).

Find a vector $(a_{1}, a_{2}, \ldots, a_{T})$ of actions, where each action $a_{k}$ is one of the four possible actions:

{ $OL$ (open long), $OS$ (open short), $C$ (lose), $SO$ (stay open), $SC$ (stay closed) },

with the objective of maximizing:
$$
\sum_{\mbox{ all } a_{k} = OL} ( -J - p_{k} A) + \sum_{\mbox{ all } a_{k} = OS} ( -J + p_{k} A),
$$
and subject to the constraints:

1. $a_{1} \neq $ $SO$ or $SC$.
2. If $a_{k} = C$, then $a_{k-1} = SO$ or $OL$ or $OS$.  (A position can be closed only if previously opened.)
3. If $a_{k} = $ $OS$ or $OL$, then $a_{k-1} = SC$ or $C$.
4. $a_{T} = $ $C$ or $SC$.

I may not have understood all the details correctly, and did not address the simultaneous closing and opening of a position, but I hope this gives you the gist and convinces you that you have a MILP.  Ping me if you need more detail.

Comment: I do not see protif in your model. You only have $p_k$ in objective of maximizing. When you open long position in time $k$ and close it in time $l$, your profit is $\frac {p_l - p_k}{p_k}A$. Having a commission it is $\frac {p_l - p_k}{p_k}A - J$. Moreover (ad 3) it is possible to close position and open another at time $t=k$ (e.g C and then OL).

Comment: Please read the disclaimers in the last two sentences of my answer.:)  For one, I didn't know your definition of profit (it is not in the Question).  As for closing a position and opening one at the same time step, I wrote at the end of my answer: **did not address the simultaneous closing and opening of a position**.  This can be addressed by extending the list of actions to include: $CTOL$ (close, then open long) and $CTOS$ (close, then open short), modifying the objective and the constraints accordingly.

Sorry if my answer is completely unhelpful.

Comment: Thank you. But I still think it is possible to solve this problem using Bellman equation (dynamic programming which can be used to discrete problems).

Comment: Not debating the feasibility of using DP, just clarified that it is a solution method, not a model.  Yes, DP can be and is used for discrete problems.